# How to sum up row sizes across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, left-join

In MySQL I have three tables:

```
A:
-----------------
|g_id  | txt    |
|------|--------|
|   1  |  cat   | 
|   3  |  dog   |
```

and

```
B:
--------------------------
|g_id  | txt     | txt2  |
|------|---------|--------
|   1  |  hat    |  chat  |
|   3  |  that   |  NULL |
|   3  |  that   |  NULL |
```

and

```
C:
------------------
|g_id  | txt     |
|------|---------|
|   1  |  hat    | 
|   1  |  mat    | 
|   3  |  that   |
```

My goal is to sum up the txt column of each row across tables A, B, and C grouped by g_id...

So after my query, the expected result would be:

```
----------------
|g_id  | size  |
|------|-------|
|   1  |  16   | 
|   3  |  15   |
```

My query fails:

```
SELECT 
   g_id,
   SUM(length(txt)) + SUM(length(txt2) as size
   FROM ((SELECT a.g_id, a.txt FROM a) UNION ALL
      (SELECT b.g_id, b.txt, b.txt2 FROM b) UNION ALL
      (SELECT c.g_id, c.txt FROM c) 
   ) abc
GROUP BY g_id;
```

Error: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Answer (score 2):

Use `union all` instead of `join`:

```
SELECT g_id,
       SUM(length(txt)) as size
FROM ((SELECT a.g_id, a.txt FROM a) UNION ALL
      (SELECT b.g_id, b.txt FROM b) UNION ALL
      (SELECT c.g_id, c.txt FROM c) 
     ) abc
GROUP BY g_id;
```

Comment: Ok so that seems to work. But in my original post, I omitted the fact that the columns I need to add up may be different across tables.
Ie., Table B might have another column 'txt2' and Table A doesn't have that column. I need to include B.txt2 in the sum.
i am getting this error: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns.
Original post has been editted

Comment: @vgbcell . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask.  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: Based on this answer, you only need to add a new select statement to the **UNION**. This will be: `(SELECT b.g_id, b.txt2 FROM b)` for the new goals you have described.